# ElasticSearch has_parent query

Tags: elasticsearch

I am experimenting with Elasticsearch parent/child with some simple examples from [fun-with-elasticsearch-s-children-and-nested-documents/](http://www.spacevatican.org/2012/6/3/fun-with-elasticsearch-s-children-and-nested-documents/). I am able to query child elements by running the query in the blog

```
curl -XPOST localhost:9200/authors/bare_author/_search -d '{
```

However, I could not tweak the example for has_parent query. Can someone please point what I am doing wrong, as I keep getting 0 results.

This is what I tried

```
#Returns 0 hits    
curl -XPOST localhost:9200/authors/book/_search -d '{
  "query": {
    "has_parent": {
      "type": "bare_author",
      "query" : {
        "filtered": {
          "query": { "match_all": {}},
          "filter" : {"term": {  "name": "Alastair Reynolds"}}            
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }'


#did not work either
curl -XPOST localhost:9200/authors/book/_search -d '{
"query": {
    "has_parent" : {
        "type" : "bare_author",
       "query" : {
        "term" : {
                "name" : "Alastair Reynolds"
            }
        }
    }
}
}'
```

This works with match but its just matching the first name

```
    #works but matches just first name
curl -XPOST localhost:9200/authors/book/_search -d '{
"query": {
    "has_parent" : {
        "type" : "bare_author",
       "query" : {
        "match" : {"name": "Alastair"}
        }
    }
  }
}'
```

Comment: You should first try to run your `term` query or filter directly on the bare_author type to see if it returns some matches. You will see if the problem comes from the `has_parent` or the `term` query.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suppose you are using the default mappings, thus analysing the name field using the [standard analyzer](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/index-modules/analysis/standard-analyzer/). On the other hand, term query and term filter don't support text analysis thus you search for the token `Alastair Reynolds` while in the index you have `alastair` and `reynolds` as two different tokens and lowercased.

The match query returns result because it's analyzed, thus underneath lowercased and it finds matches. You can just change your [term query](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/query-dsl/term-query/) and make it a [match query](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/query-dsl/match-query/), it will find matches even with multiple terms, because in that case it will be tokenized on whitespaces and will generate a boolean or dismax query out of the different terms provided.

Comment: You were correct. To fix this, I deleted the index and recreated with not_analyzed.